# What is wrong with this code Python?

Tags: python

this question is more regarding understanding of what went wrong in the code that I have compiled.

Basically this code counts and tells you the amount of descendants a person has.

```
class Person:
    """Person class.

    Attributes:
    - name (str): The name of this Person
    - children (list of Person): a list of the Person objects who
                             are the children of this Person
    """

    def __init__(self, name):
        """ (Person, str) -> NoneType
        Create a new person with the given name, and no children.
        """
        self.name = name
        self.children = []
        i = 0
        self.l = self.children

    def recur(l):
        if not l:
            return 0
        else:
            return recur(l[1:]) + len(l[0])

    def count_descendants(self):
        """ (Person) -> int
        Return the number of descendants of self.
        """
        children = self.children

        recur(children)
```

I am getting a name error:

```
NameError: name 'recur' is not defined
```

Comment: Should be `self.recur()`, or better, move `recur()` out of the class entirely, since it doesn't need to be in there. If you do leave it in the class, you'll need to make it accept a `self` parameter, which it currently does not (it'll interpret `l` as `self`, which is not what you want).

Comment: All of them that don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need your `recur()` function at all, since all `count_descendants()` does is to call it. Your calculation of the number of descendants is also incorrect.

Here's a simplified and corrected version of your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.children = []

    def count_descendants(self):
        if not self.children:
            return 0
        else:
            n = len(self.children)
            for kid in self.children:
                n += kid.count_descendants()
            return n

a = Person('a')
b = Person('b')
c = Person('c')
d = Person('d')
e = Person('e')
f = Person('f')
g = Person('g')
h = Person('h')

a.children = [b, c, d]
b.children = [e]
c.children = [f, g]
f.children = [h]

for p in [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]:
    print p.name + ' has ' + str(p.count_descendants()) + ' descendants'
```

which outputs:

```
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox$ ./desc.py
a has 7 descendants
b has 1 descendants
c has 3 descendants
d has 0 descendants
e has 0 descendants
f has 1 descendants
g has 0 descendants
h has 0 descendants
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox$
```

The number of descendants that a person has is the number of its own children, plus the sum of all its children's descendants. The number of each of it's children's descendants its the number of *it's* own children, plus the sum of......and so on. Here's where you get your recursion. The revised `count_descendants()` method above implements this algorithm.

Comment: oh I see what you did. You made a for loop and looped through the children and found their children and looped through that.. till there were no more desendants... went back up and looped through other childrens decendants.

Comment: @Ali: Essentially, yes. If each person knows how to count its descendants, then it can calculate the number of its own children, and delegate the task of calculating *their* descendants to them. At some point (hopefully) each branch will reach a person that has no children, so your recursion will end, and your calculation will finish.